# Eta-products and modular elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, examples, modular-forms

Recently the elliptic curve $E:y^2+y=x^3-x^2$ of conductor $11$ (which appears in [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers/32939#32939)) became my favourite elliptic over $\bf Q$ because the associated modular form
$$
F=q\prod_{n>0}(1-q^n)^2(1-q^{11n})^2
$$
is such a nice "$\eta$-product".  (This modular form is also associated to the isogenous elliptic curve
$y^2+y=x^3-x^2-10x-20$ which appears in [Franz's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32964/quaternary-quadratic-forms-and-elliptic-curves-via-langlands).)

**Question.** Are there other elliptic curves over $\bf Q$ which have a simple minimal equation and whose associated modular form is a nice $\eta$-product or even a nice $\eta$-quotient?

I know two references which might have a bearing on the question

--- [Koike's article on McKay's conjecture](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-95/issue-none/On-McKays-conjecture/nmj/1118787564.full)

and

--- [p.18](https://books.google.com/books?id=MLdRYIg6pDkC&lpg=PR1&dq=ono%25252520web%25252520of%25252520modularity&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Ono's *Web of modularity* on $\eta$-quotients.

Can someone provide a partial or exhaustive list of such nice pairs $(E,F)$ ?

Comment: Actually Kilford has a great paper on generating spaces of modular forms using linear combinations of Dedekind Eta-functions (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701478). They have a less elegant form though. 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an exhaustive list in the paper [Y. Martin and K. Ono, Eta-Quotients and Elliptic
Curves, *Proc. Amer. Math Soc.* **125** (1997), no. 11, 3169--3176]. 
Suppose that $E_N$ is an elliptic curve of conductor
$N$, then the corresponding $L$-series is assigned to the eta product
$$
\eta(a\tau)\eta(ab\tau)\eta(ac\tau)\eta(abc\tau),
$$
where $a+ab+ac+abc=24$, $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$,
for the following values of $N$ and $(b,c)$:
$$    \begin{align*}
        N &\quad (b,c)\cr
        11 &\quad (1,11)\cr
        14 &\quad (2,7)\cr
        15 &\quad (3,5)\cr
        20 &\quad (1,5)\cr
        24 &\quad (2,3)\cr
        27 &\quad (1,3)\cr
        32 &\quad (1,2)\cr
        36 &\quad (1,1)\cr
    \end{align*}
$$
It is probably more exciting that all these elliptic curves and their $L$-series at $s=2$ appear in Boyd's conjectures on Mahler's measure. For a nice review of this story see
[M.D. Rogers, Hypergeometric formulas for lattice sums and Mahler measures, [arXiv:0806.3590](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3590)] and the original paper [D.W. Boyd, Mahler's measure and special values of $L$-functions, *Experiment. Math.* **7** (1998) 37--82].

Comment: How wonderful!  Many thanks for the references.  It is surprising that the Martin-Ono paper is so recent...

Comment: You are welcome, Chandan. A lot of interesting nontrivial identities for eta products are given by Michael Somos (see, for example, cis.csuohio.edu/~somos/retaprod.pdf). They are also discussed in the Zagier's lectures in *1-2-3 of Modular Forms*.

Answer (score 9):

*This won't fit into a comment box so here it is :*

I came across another small nugget in Kilford's book  (p.101) this afternoon.  Let $k>0$, $N>0$ be integers such that $k.(N+1)=24$, namely one of the pairs

$(12,1)$, $(8,2)$, $(6,3)$, $(4,5)$, $(3,7)$, $(2,11)$, or $(1,23)$.

Then $(\eta(q)\eta(q^N))^k$ is in $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ unless $k=1$ or $k=3$, in which case it is in $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),({{}\over N}))$.  This implies in particular that the form

$q\prod_{n>0}(1-q^n)(1-q^{23n})$

which appears in [Emerton's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers/12382#12382)  belongs to $S_1(\Gamma_0(23),({{}\over 23}))$.

Comment: This result is also in Koblitz and is used by Kilford to show that every modular form of even weight of $\Gamma(2)$ is generated by eta-quotients.

Answer (score 2):

Today I came across the following theorem of Mersmann: *There are precisely* 14 *primitive eta-products which are holomorphic modular forms of weight* $\frac{1}{2}$, [*namely*...](http://books.google.com/books?id=tsTfnHLmgmQC&lpg=PA23&dq=subject%253A%2522Mathematics%2522%2520ramanujan%2520tau%2520function&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=Mersmann&f=false)

He also proves a conjecture of Zagier to the effect that there are essentially only finitely many such products of any given weight.

I learnt these facts from Zagier's contribution to the [*The 1-2-3 of modular forms*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tsTfnHLmgmQC&lpg=PA23&dq=subject%253A%2522Mathematics%2522%2520ramanujan%2520tau%2520function&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (which happens to have been metioned by Wadim Zudilin).

**Addendum** (2011/02/10)  Came across an advertisement for the book [*Eta products and theta series identities*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-3-642-16151-3) by Günter Köhler.