Applications of Langlands for GLn explicit reciprocity laws other than elliptic curves
Is there any explicit application of Langlands conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}(n)$
for $n\ge 3$, to get some reciprocity laws for higher dimensional varieties or higher genus curves?
I've never found such things in articles such like "What is a reciprocity law?", Ana Caraiani's "Higher-dimensional reciprocity laws" or "Reciprocity laws and Galois representations: recent breakthroughs".
MSE link

Do you mean an application of the conjecture or of known theorems toward the conjecture?

I mean application

For genus $2$ curves there is the recent work of Boxer--Calegari--Gee--Pilloni, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09269.

What do you mean by "Langlands conjecture"?  Langlands made a number of conjectures.  Do you mean this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/298944

I mean the Global Langlands for GL(n) in this article https://math.berkeley.edu/~sander/speaking/25October2017%20NT%20Talk.pdf

See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32964/quaternary-quadratic-forms-and-elliptic-curves-via-langlands
